# Why does the price of firewood from Ardennes forests rise when the price of natural gas from the North Sea rises?

Tags: elasticity, price, elasticity-of-substitution, cross-price-elasticity

I have an exam question from last year that I don't understand. I have to explain this : why does the price of firewood from Ardennes forests rise when the price of natural gas from the North Sea rises?

Wouldn't that have to do with cross-elasticity (the problem is I think these goods are substitutes...) ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Ps my exam is tomorow ;)

Comment: Maybe they are both correlated to some other variable like cold weather

Comment: I usually heat with gas, but also have a fireplace at home.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what do you mean with that ?

Comment: When gas prices are too high, I use my fireplace...

Comment: Alright sorry it was a stupid question...